# MS access 2013 - Report - VBA

Tags: report, checkboxlist

I am new in MS access VBA.

I want to generate Report with list having checked actions only instead of generating all action list in MS Access 2013:

[image: Example]

I have attached photo for your referance.

Comment: Please specify what have you tried, and whenever possible don't rely on external images. =)

Comment: I have created form by entering task list - Action 1 , Action 2 & Action 3 for which i have check box (Y/N) for field Advised And Field complete. I want to generate report with only Actions with if Advised field or Completed fields are checked with trim spaces. As shown in Image. If for action 3 neither Advised or Comleted checked then it should not in the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it that way you can use an image of checked and unchecked image by saving it to your database or external then query it on your Report

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wingdings font. Substitute the true values with the wingding font checked character and false values with unchecked character.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfwzt.png)